# facebook application development:: which sdk is best for facebook application development?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to facebook app development.
I found fb app can be developed using Php sdk/javascript sdk/ python sdk/ ruby on rails sdk/ java sdk.

I want to know which is best sdk for developing fd app out of

1. php sdk
2. python sdk
3. java script sdk
4. ruby on rails sdk
5. java sdk

which type of application development is suited to above mentioned sdk.

what are the comparison for different sdk as per fb app development?

Comment: Read the documentation and find out which SDK suits you.

Comment: All the sdk are good at there place and all are doing the same thing at the end.
Kindly think about on which language you are conformable and choose that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application doesn't need or have a server side component, you may want to go with the js sdk for simplicity, otherwise use the sdk that corresponds with the language you are most comfortable with, or the language you will be using on the back end.